# What Should I Read To Become Familiar with Developing using SocialEngine?

Tags: zend-framework, web, socialengine

I am capable with PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript and SQL, and not bad with Drupal. Very recently, I acquired a customer that wants me to do some SocialEngine 4.xxx customization. My customer is aware that I have no experience with SocialEngine, but am capable with the underlying technologies (I gave him a lower hourly rate because of this too.)

I'm not seeing very much online that is geared towards someone like me. Where can I read about modifying SocialEngine that assumes very little knowledge about SocialEngine, but a competency at programming?

For example, I spent a few hours today trying to figure out how to conditionally display a block based on a Membership Level. It appears there is no way to do this using the GUI. No problem, I [found some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520448/understanding-user-permissions-and-how-to-apply-it) that seemed like I could get it to work that would grab the user's membership level. However, where do I put this? Honestly, I'd like to have this at the block-level. SocialEngine doesn't seem to allow me to place arbitrary PHP code into a block, and even if it did, would that be the "SocialEngine" way of doing this? Should all custom logic like this be a module in SocialEngine, that attaches to events using hooks?

Thank you very much for looking at my question,

-Brian J. Stinar-

Comment: Thankfully, I am no longer using SocialEngine for anything. I highly recommend something like BuddyPress if you're trying to accomplish this. SocialEngine is not the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a blog about accessing data through models, creating widgets and modules. You can find out about the general structure of Social Engine at http://garbtech.co.uk / http://socialenginetutorials.co.uk (both same blog)

Comment: Thanks! I am totally done with the Social Engine project, but your blog post probably would have helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no books or official documentation on SocialEngine PHP API. Your only choice is to check out various (incomplete) guides over the Internet or study their source code and figure things out by yourself.